# Geometry Nodes - How to rotate multiple instances?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I have created a geometry nodes setup which animates multiple objects along a spline, like a tank track. I want to duplicate and rotate this entire set of objects, for example having 4 sets of tank tracks at 45 degrees to each other. How would I achieve this?

It would be the equivalent of linking the duplicate index to the set position node, but I have tried various ideas and can't work out how to make this work for rotations. Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to a possible solution. I've used a simple quadrilateral (FAKE INSTANCE) in place of your spline and rotated by instancing them on points along a control curve. I capture the `Factor` before creating points and set the rotation along the spline.

[image]

Here are my geometry nodes for this.

[image]

I suppose the biggest difference is the use of the `Spline Parameter Factor` instead of an `Index`.

Comment: Although it's a workaround regarding instances, this solution is actually a better approach for my problem. Using a curve makes it easier to offset the position of the rotated objects.